# How to hide div on click or click out of div

Tags: javascript, show-hide

This code shows a div on click from a button but I'd like to hide the div when the user clicks somewhere else or if an item within the div is clicked.

```
function show_menu(){
    var menu = document.getElementById('dropdown_menu');

    if(menu.style.display == 'block'){
        menu.style.display = 'none';
    }else {
        menu.style.display = 'block';                    
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a bit of a FAQ. You need to set an event handler on document and test the target. If it is your button, toggle, else hide. Here is a jQUery example: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/Uk57k/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show hide div in one area](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598919/show-hide-div-in-one-area)

Answer (score 2):

Given this simplified HTML:

```
<div id="myDiv"> myDiv </div>
```

Use this simplfied javascript:

```
var div = document.getElementById("myDiv");

// event gets passed and represents the DOM event

document.onclick = function( event ){
    console.log("outside");
    if( event.toElement !== div ){
        div.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
};

div.onclick = function( event ){
    console.log("inside");
    event.toElement.style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

this basically hides your div wether you click on it or not, so I'm not completely sure about it's application. So in short, if you want to hide the div wether someone clicks inside it or outside, just use the following, but then again, I don't see it's usefullness:

```
document.onlick = function(){ 
  document.getElementById("myDiv").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to recreate a functional drop down menu like this:

<Select name="to_folder">
<option value="">- move to folder -</option>
<option value="0"> / </option>
<option value="1">folder 1</option>
<option value="2">folder 2</option>
</Select>

but I'm using divs because I want to activate 'onClick' functions instead of selecting an item and pressing 'Submit'. Hopefully that clears up the idea :D

Comment: Use onchange of the select

Answer (score 0):

Use `.children() selector`
http://api.jquery.com/children/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WMJc5/2/

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <style>
  #mydiv p,#mydiv a,#mydiv h3,#mydiv div,#mydiv span{background-color:red;}
 </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mydiv" style="border:1px solid;">
    <p>p tag</p>
      <a >a tag</a><br>
      <h3>H3</h3><br>
      <div>inner div</div><br>
      <span>444</span>
    </div>
   <script>
   $( "#mydiv *" ).click(function () {$( "#mydiv" ).hide();});
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: that does not hide the hide when clicked outside

Comment: If he want to hide div when click anywhere must use `$( "body" ).click(function () {$( "#mydiv" ).hide();});`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your comment is telling us what you REALLY want then something like this

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/vGpT5/)

```
$(function() {
  $("#to_folder").on("change",function() {
    $(".folder").hide();
    var folderId = this.value;
    if (folderId !="") {
      $("#folder"+folderId).show();
    }
  });
  $("#to_folder").trigger("change"); // show/hide whatever matches the select
});
```

using

```
<select id="to_folder" name="to_folder"> 
  <option value="">- move to folder -</option> 
  <option value="0"> / </option> 
  <option value="1">folder 1</option> 
  <option value="2">folder 2</option> 
</select>
<div class="folder" id="folder0">/</div>
<div class="folder" id="folder1">1</div>
<div class="folder" id="folder2">2</div>
```

with the divs hidden initially